# choose rows that have the same value in mysql

Tags: mysql

In a [KHS] table, some rows have the same value for the id_student and courses column.
and i would like to choose higher "KE" column if they have id_student and courses column..

| id_grade | id_student | courses | ke |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | A | 2 |
| 2 | 2001 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 2001 | B | 1 |
| 4 | 2002 | A | 2 |
| 5 | 2002 | A | 1 |

and expected result is:

| id_grade | id_student | courses | ke |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | A | 2 |
| 3 | 2001 | B | 1 |
| 4 | 2002 | A | 2 |

What SQL statement should I use ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id_grade, id_student, courses, max(ke) ke
from temp
group by id_student, courses
```